# Vaccum observation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I really know that information have its entropy. So I guess that there's some symmetry breaking after observing vaccum. Here's my **question**: does observing vaccum can affect its state? Or this is nothing but quantum fluctuation?